# How can I close this jQuery modal I wrote?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, zurb-foundation

Good afternoon everyone!

I'm trying to code a simple JS modal that works for opening it and everything.. However, I added a click function to click on (.black-overlay) to fadeOut everything to close the modal.

```
<div class="black-overlay"></div>
<div id="play-button">
    <a id="video-click" href="#">
        <img src="img/home/video-play.png" alt="Check out our video">
    </a>
</div>

<div id="welcome-video">
    <iframe class="vimeo-video" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/83267186?autoplay=1" width="722" height="406" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div><!--#welcome-video-->
```

And then here is my JS..

```
$("#video-click").click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('#video-click').hide();
    $('#welcome-video').show();
    $('.panel2 .black-overlay').fadeIn();
});

var iframe = $('.vimeo-video')[0],
player = $f(iframe);

$('.panel2 .black-overlay').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $('.panel2 .black-overlay').fadeOut();
    $('#welcome-video').fadeOut();
    $('#video-click').fadeIn();
    var video = $('iframe').attr("src");
    $('iframe.vimeo-video').attr("src","");
    $('iframe.vimeo-video').attr("src",video);// sets it back to the correct link so that it reloads immediately on the next window open
    $('iframe.vimeo-video').attr('src','//player.vimeo.com/video/83267186?autoplay=1');
});
```

I could've swore this was right to close it and I've tried multiple methods and disabling other JS on my site.

Here is the live preview of the site if you want to see what's going on and it's the second panel with a play button in the middle. Here is the link! http://bit.ly/1eGCShX

Any help is kindly appreciated as I've been on this for awhile! Have a wonderful weekend everyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo:

```
player = $f(iframe);
```

should be:

```
player = $(iframe);
```

`Uncaught ReferenceError: $f is not defined` on line 10 of vimeoModal.js

Comment: Ahhhhh! Thanks so much Matthew. It's just one of those things...

EDIT: I also didn't realize I was doing an anonymous function which I don't really understand what it does. Glad, it works without it now!

I'll be sure to look through the console more often!

Comment: Happy to help. :) You can check for js bugs like this by opening the dev console of your browser.